# Update or create an objects in array based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi this is my array of objects:

```
notes:Array(3)
0:Object
1497752995725:
"{"id":"1497752995725","top":"470.047px","left":"1130px","text":""}"

1:Object
1497753006544:"{"id":"1497753006544","top":"470.047px","left":"1130px","text":"dadssad"}"

2:Object
1497753006544:
"{"id":"1497753006544","top":"325.047px","left":"585px","text":"dadssad"}"
```

and the code I'm using:

```
var notes = []
var obj = {
      id: sticky.attr('id'),
      top: sticky.css('top'),
      left: sticky.css('left'),
      text: sticky.children('.sticky-content').html()
      }

var item = {}
item[obj.id] = JSON.stringify(obj)
notes.push(item)
```

I would like to have this type of output:

```
notes:Array(3)
1497752995725:
"{"id":"1497752995725","top":"470.047px","left":"1130px","text":""}"
1497753006544:
"{"id":"1497753006544","top":"470.047px","left":"1130px","text":"dadssad"}"
1497753006544:
"{"id":"1497753006544","top":"325.047px","left":"585px","text":"dadssad"}"
```

The notes can be an array or object so when the key eg. 1497752995725 exist the object value of the key will be updated when not the key 1497752995725 will be created with the new body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep notes as an object

```
var notes = {}

var obj = {
  id: sticky.attr('id'),
  top: sticky.css('top'),
  left: sticky.css('left'),
  text: sticky.children('.sticky-content').html()
}
notes[obj.id] = obj
```

It'll update data for the same key.